# How to refresh a web page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In my code i added dynamically some text-boxes and labels.
Then by dropdownlist event i want to refresh the page in a way that all the added text-boxes and labels will remove from aspx

how can it be done?

Comment: Set the DropDownList's AutoPostBack property to "True" and then remove them in the event handler.

Comment: I set the DropDownList's AutoPostBack property to "True"

Comment: what do you mean by remove them in the event handler, how?

Comment: Or add them only on initial load where IsPostback == false

Comment: That sort of depends on how they were added.  You haven't given us much to go on...

Comment: I added them dynamicly by adding them to a panel. TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.ID = "tb" + i.ToString();
                tb.Width = 106;
                tb.Text = itemList[i].amount;
                Panel2.Controls.Add(tb);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using C#.

You can redirect to the current page by doing this from your code-behind:

```
Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `AutoPostBack="True"` for the DropDownList
2. Add an event to DropDownList for SelectedIndexChange
   `OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"`
3. In the Code-Behind file :

   ```
   private void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
       {
           Label1.Visible = false;
       }
       else
       {
           Label2.Visible = false;
       }
   }
   ```